# Execute javascript function on ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use the following ajax function to call a webservice, if I get an error I would like it to trigger a javascript function userCreate()

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("X-DreamFactory-Application-Name", "snapcentral");
        request.setRequestHeader("X-DreamFactory-Session-Token", sessID.dream);
    },
    url: url,
    data: '{"username":"' + userStats.loginID + '","lithid":"' + userStats.userID + '"}',
    success: function(data) {
        dbData = data;
        console.log('createUsers Executed sucessfully');
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log("createUser: " + request.responseText);
        createUser();
    }
});
```

Everything works as expected apart from the "error" section not triggering the createUser() function. What am I doing fundamentally wrong and how do I get the query to execute a function on error.

The function I have written for createUser works if I call standalone..

Advise and/or direction would be most welcome - thanks.

Comment: Is the error section not logging, or just not triggering the function?

Comment: Why would the error callback be called, are you expecting an error with your ajax call, or do you just think it will be called if you return "no user" or "false" ?

Comment: error callback is triggered when a request error is detected (i.ex. 404, or unable to connect), not when you response with a custom error.

Comment: the ajax itself is looking for a specific user so if that fails I get the following error:

Could not find record for id = '37'

In which case I would like to call createUser().

If I am going about this all wrong I am open to ideas.

Comment: @CarlDraper that is a custom message you send back...Need to process your data in success callback to determine if user exists or not. The request has been successful

Comment: can someone please have a look of this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034536/ajax-call-in-httpfox-shows-error-as-error-loading-content-ns-error-document-no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `error` callback is only called if the server responds with an error code, or doesn't respond at all.  If you respond with `200` and an error message in your response, the `success` callback will be called.  Sadly, jQuery isn't that smart.

Instead, you can either return an error code or check in your `success` callback if there's a error message.

Comment: Of course your right! Although its an error in my mind ajax sees it as a success because the response code is 200.

Comment: @SomeKitten : hi can you please see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034536/ajax-call-in-httpfox-shows-error-as-error-loading-content-ns-error-document-no

Answer (score 0):

Like @SomeKittens mentioned, `error` is only called when the server responds with an error code or doesn't reply at all.

However, you can return something on serverside, if something went wrong, such as form validation wasn't successful, and user needs to correct something.

For example this:

```
if($_POST['first_last'] === ""){
echo "Name is not right here.";
return false;
}
```

Then, you can use the `success` on your jQuery to process this:

```
success: function(data) {
  if(data == "Name is not right here."){
    alert(data);
    return false;
  }
  else{
  // do stuff
  }
 }
```