# Ajax call is not calling to the server side and in httpfox shows error as "Error loading content (NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED)" in ajax post call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jsonp, json.net

Here I am making a simple ajax post call  from my asp.net page which shows following error on httpfox. 
"Error loading content (NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED)"
and

```
 error: function () { alert(arguments[2]); }
```

of my ajax call displays alert message as "Internal server error"

Here i am creating a JSON array and convering that json array to a JSON String and passing  as a parameter to the Server side method.

here is my ajax call

```
 $('#btnResult').on('click', function () {
            var myObject = new Object();

            $("#<%=GridProjectDetails.ClientID %>  tr").each(function () {
                var id = $(this).find("input[name*='ID']").val();
                var locationcode = $(this).find("input[name*='TextLocationCode']").val();
                var Location = $(this).find("input[name*='TextLocation']").val();
                myObject.id = id;
                myObject.locationcode = locationcode;
                myObject.Location = Location;
            });

            var myString = JSON.stringify(myObject);
            alert(myString);
            var exportdata = myString;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/ExportToExcel",
                data: exportdata,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#Result").text(data.d);
                },
                error: function () { alert(arguments[2]); }
            });
        });
    });
```

and here is my server side code

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string ExportToExcel(string details)
    {

        return "Message : Success";
    }
```

Any Idea ? What's happening here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your responses.

Today i got the answer after googling for more than 1 hr.

> > > > Things i learned is while sending json data using stringfy() method, in server side we need to define the parameter as object. not any other format like string/int/bla bla.....

Actually there was a mistake on my Server side parameter.I modified it from string to object and it worked for me. Here i have defined my modified answer.

```
        $('#btnResult').on('click', function () {

        var mydata = [];
        $("#<%=GridProjectDetails.ClientID %>  tr").each(function () {
            var myObject = new Object();
            var id = $(this).find("input[name*='ID']").val();
            var locationcode = $(this).find("input[name*='TextLocationCode']").val();
            var Location = $(this).find("input[name*='TextLocation']").val();
            myObject.id = id;
            myObject.locationcode = locationcode;
            myObject.Location = Location;
            mydata.push(myObject);
        });

        var myString = JSON.stringify({ details: JSON.stringify(mydata) });
        alert(myString);
        var exportdata = myString;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/ExportToExcel",
            data: exportdata,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#Result").text(data.d);
            },
            error: function () { alert(arguments[2]); }
        });
    });
});
```

and my server side method should be

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string ExportToExcel(object details)
{

    return "Message : Success";
}
```

Comment: Basically copied answer. The javascript code that you provided is identical with my own, except few variables with different names and the server side code works fine with details parameter being string type or object.

Comment: @ Ilija Dimov i was getting error : which httpfox shows and it was not calling to my server side as the parameter was wrong. It has lost my one night. After a long try i got it. When i executed your code what error i got , that i have defined in your answer comment. Anyway thanks for your help. i have appreciated you for the percentage of help you made for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$('#btnResult').on('click', function () {
        var myArray = [];

        $("#<%=GridProjectDetails.ClientID %>  tr").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).find("input[name*='ID']").val();
            var locationcode = $(this).find("input[name*='TextLocationCode']").val();
            var Location = $(this).find("input[name*='TextLocation']").val();
            var myObject = new Object();
            myObject.id = id;
            myObject.locationcode = locationcode;
            myObject.Location = Location;
            myArray.push(myObject);
        });

        var myString = JSON.stringify({details: JSON.stringify(myArray)});
        alert(myString);
        var exportdata = myString;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/ExportToExcel",
            data: exportdata,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#Result").text(data.d);
            },
            error: function () { alert(arguments[2]); }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hi Thanks for the answer. But still i am getting error and it is not calling to the server side method.

Comment: it shows following error in httpfox : {"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027dataJsonString\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n

Comment: at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

Comment: As I see from the stack trace, the exception is "missing value for parameter data". The parameter in the WebMethod is called "details" in the sample you provided.

Comment: Thanks. You answer helped me 30%. define array , add objects from loop to array and stringfy using Two stringfy methods...helped me.

Answer (score 0):

**Send data using following method**

```
 data: "{'details':" + myString "}",
```