# Passing an array from javascript to code behind - C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my website, i'm declaring an array in javascript and insert them elements dynamically. So now, I want use that array from my C# code. I don't want use ajax to send that element to an web service... I just want use an C# event, like OnClick and access the array that was build in javascript.

I searched for an answer but I just found the oposite.
Thanks

Comment: If you want to go from client to server you're going to have to implement ajax on some level.

Comment: You'll have to store the value of that array, serialized to JSON, in a hidden field. You could then access that hidden field on click, deserialize it, and work with it server-side.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between _server-side_ code and _client-side_ code.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is AJAX call and i don't understand why you are avoiding that ?

Make an AJAX call from your button click.

look here a demo : 
[Ajax call is not calling to the server side and in httpfox shows error as "Error loading content (NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED)" in ajax post call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034536/ajax-call-is-not-calling-to-the-server-side-and-in-httpfox-shows-error-as-error)

for example : covert your array to a json string and call a web client in your c# code. Here i have a button . on button click i want to send my GRIDVIEW data  to c# method(web method).

you need to remember that while sending json data using `stringfy()` method, 
in server side we need to define the parameter as object. 
not any other format like string/int/bla bla.....
use `Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js` 
        http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js

```
 $('#btnResult').on('click', function () {

        var mydata = [];
        $("#<%=GridProjectDetails.ClientID %>  tr").each(function () {
            var myObject = new Object();
            var id = $(this).find("input[name*='ID']").val();
            var locationcode = $(this).find("input[name*='TextLocationCode']").val();
            var Location = $(this).find("input[name*='TextLocation']").val();
            myObject.id = id;
            myObject.locationcode = locationcode;
            myObject.Location = Location;
            mydata.push(myObject);
        });

        var myString = JSON.stringify({ details: JSON.stringify(mydata) });
        alert(myString);
        var exportdata = myString;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/ExportToExcel",
            data: exportdata,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#Result").text(data.d);
            },
            error: function () { alert(arguments[2]); }
        });
    });
});
```

and server side method should be

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string ExportToExcel(object details)
{
     return "Message : Success";
}
```

Comment: Because I want submit a form that has an uploadFile and an array. So, I can't/don't know how to use an web method that recieve file and an array at same time, I decided create an event click, so I can access to my uploadFile control easly.

Comment: What's the problem there man ? File upload will do it's task. What you need to do is get the path and create connection string for your excel/csv file to access. I hope you have done all these stuffs. no probs. export/Import using ajax on a button click - is so easy.

Answer (score 0):

It's a kinda weird thing to do, but if you have to do it, you can do it by creating a form, inside the form have a hidden text field and call a function when submitting to update the value of this field.

The markup:

```
<form id="yourForm" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="hiddenFieldName" id="hiddenFieldName" hidden="hidden" />
</form>
```

The javascript:

```
void yourProcedure() {
    var yourArray = ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4"];
    document.getElementById('hiddenFieldName').value = yourArray.join();
    document.getElementById("yourForm").submit();
}
```

Then in the server, the form variable will contain "Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4".

Comment: What you will do if the array values frequently changes ?

Comment: What will change the array values?  And if the server needs to know about every change, you cannot avoid HTTP post or get methods so we would want to know *what* the server is doing with the array values as they frequently change before deciding on the solution :-)