# Javascript Post error

Tags: javascript, post

Hello guys i have a weird problem with my javascript code.

```
$.ajax({
                url : "http://requestb.in/1k8rvk71",
                type: "POST",
                data : formData,
                success: function(){
                    alert('success');
                                    },
                error: function(kl){
                    alert(kl);
                                }
                        });
```

First of all it is succesfully posting the formData but i dont why its executing the error function and it alerts "[object Object]"

Comment: Unless we see some server code, we can't know either. Look in your browser debugger the message in the response.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034352/execute-javascript-function-on-ajax-error

Comment: Are you making the request from the same domain?

Comment: do console.log(kl); and see the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `alert` with `console.log`, and you will get the error response in console.
May help!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to print an object
try to use console.log and print the error to the console instead using alert

Answer (score 0):

Check the status code the request is returning. If it's different then 200 then the error is probably in the server.